# How to extract keys from an interface to which a certain type can be assigned?

Tags: typescript

Given an interface `Foo`, I want to extract the keys in `Foo` to whose values I can assign values of type `T`.

For instance,

```js
interface Foo {
  num: number
  null: null
  undefined: undefined
  nullNum: number | null
  unNum: number | undefined
  unNull: null | undefined
  nullishNum: number | null | undefined
}
```

From this interface I would like to extract all keys whose values have the type `number | null | undefined`, i.e., `nullishNum`.

Test cases:

```
let prop: AssignableProps<Foo, number | null | undefined>

// @ts-expect-error because neither null nor undefined are assignable
prop = 'num' as const
// @ts-expect-error because neither number nor undefined are assignable
prop = 'null' as const
// @ts-expect-error because neither number nor null are assignable
prop = 'undefined' as const
// @ts-expect-error because neither undefined is not assignable
prop = 'nullNum' as const
// @ts-expect-error because null is not assignable
prop = 'unNum' as const
// @ts-expect-error because number is not assignable
prop = 'unNull' as const
// Should work
prop = 'nullishNum' as const
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIgCuAtgFyGkBG0%20lANvRcY3USACYQygQcXsuPEHzot6AOVLNq0ZAB8G9NiCnlKJGlAXJB3XhxVTGMxjr3DRBccADOACzUzNcxePOd9IwwF9cuMABPAAcUAEFbW2AAcxA4KnoIAAUodGDbAB4AIThbCAAaZAio2IA%20ZABeHABtAGsIQORQZHrA9BhkHLyAXQouiDqG7uQIAA9ITlsiyJiQZAB%20FobkZggAN2g-XESwZGDU4Ipi2fjElLTMjHRC4hdtNyIzRQsDUv8AenfkAAEwWwBaMahBBgQFQVLaGgIOBEPKECDAMD2OTuEDobQvbzIOBQFC5EpxBIQXD7NKVZAAcluFOxUwQ6BAtjAuE%20Pz%20gNGwNB0AhyChMLhIkRyO0ty0hHRuk8lg42NxtIJp2JpOC5Kpj3oNNyyHpjOZrN%20AKBEBBYN5-NhKCFSJRslFkvcOLxM1iSpJBzVmL4WrpDKZLK%20ho5XLNkotgoRNox0oMTSmaN2%20JORPdZKq6sYah9Or9%20sD7ONpp5YZNAqtGrjEsTLsJiVTqvT7CztJzeoDbKNnJN3PBJehlo04rsVYVybrKs9qg12d1-tZAGV7OhHrKAO7o2r1tU2BzN7WzsBAA)

I have tried defining `AssignableProps` as follows, but it seems like it returns an empty type, since nothing is assignable to `prop`.

```js
type AssignableProps<Base, Assign> = {
  [key in keyof Base]: Base[key] extends Assign
    ? key
    : never
}
```

For context: I intend to use this to reduce the boilerplate code for fetching data and handling errors. A basic example would be:

```js
let obj: { users: User[] | null | undefined, bar: number }
get(obj, 'users', getUsers)

function get<T, S>(obj: T, key: AssignableProps<T, S>, getter: () => Promise<S>) {
  obj[key] = undefined // Data is not yet fetched
  try {
    obj[key] = await getter() // Get data from backend
  } catch(e) {
    obj[key] = null // Error while fetching
  }
}

function getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  return fetch(/**/).json()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The conditional should be reversed, `Assign extends ...` instead of `... extends Assign`
2. Wrap the types in brackets to disable distribution (making them tuples), `[Assign] extends [...]`
3. Extract the result as a union with keyof: `{ ... }[keyof Base]`
4. More nit-picky but `key` should be capitalized, `[Key in keyof Base]: ...`

```
type AssignableProps<Base, Assign> = {
    [Key in keyof Base]: [Assign] extends [Base[Key]] ? Key : never;
}[keyof Base];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIgCuAtgFxFkBG0A3PoSQDbOUvMOHLEgAmEGKAh9KvAUJAiuTYqwByZdjWjIAPlVYyCvRRSqlaUdT36DhfbacWtlrE+PNTLjAh2ABnABZ7lh1RocDmaS0rgAvri4YACeAA4oAIIeHsAA5iBw1MwQAApQ6HEeADwAQnAeEAA0yMmpGQB8yAC8OK7IANoA0hAxyKDIANa96DDI5ZUAupQddekgk8gQAB6Q-B6dExDdvZOLAPzIPX3sEABu9BEdwzGj4xUQkwy4OWDIcQVxlHMZWTn5hRKGHQNRI-mMgTkzGCEgsDWeAHoEcgAAJgDwAWhWCQQYCxUAKxloCDgxEqRAgwDAXlUQRA6GMjlCfGQcCgKAq9Uy2QguA+hRayAARGChayNgh0CAPGAGEjUeiscscXjoITkMTSeSpFSacYwUYiAzTLDnKz2eKuX9efy4oKRVCxRVkJLpbLcPK0ZjsRBcfj1ZqySgddTaSp9cagmyOSl5ta+Z97UyLE6JVKZXLkV6lSr-cbA9rKaHGSELP0NvS3py4zyEwLWg6FGRUy70+7PYqfX61fnfVrg1Dy0aq7HfrXbUmQHoW66Mx6s53lb7VQTeySgwZDZ5h5aazk63aG7pHeLW27M8gAMpedByFkAdwZgwP9vc3mnp9n7qAA)

Comment: Generic params and such don't _have_ to be capitalized. As you said, it's a nit-picky and controversial thing. The author of [TS Pattern](https://github.com/gvergnaud/ts-pattern) advocates lowercase, for example.